# Show caption and title fancybox 3

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'd like to display a caption AND a title with Fancybox 3. Right now captions are displayed with the data-caption attribute. I've scanned the documentation but didn't find anything. The only solutions I've found on here or elsewhere are good for Fancybox 2. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize caption area to your liking, there are a plenty of demos - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-2

Comment: This is no good. We need a separate title element that is not a part of the caption element, so that we can easily display it above the images.

Comment: Maybe you can create a  sketch (or show some example) that shows the desired layout?

Comment: just imagine a typical Image in the lightbox. At the top there is the toolbar, at the bottom the caption. We need the title to go above the image, centered. So basically, it looks like a part of the toolbar (in the center).

I resolved this myself using a hack- I added <span class="title">MY TITLE</span> In the data-caption attreibute itself, then gave it some CSS, i.e. position: fixed;, top: 1rem; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -0%) etc....just a basic title for the slides that goes above. Obviously this CSS is hacky and not ideal.